# How to remove a \n newline delimiter in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I want to compare some genome sequence raw data by 23andme and use Python for that.

I have imported my data like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

sample_1 = pd.read_csv('sample_1.txt', delimiter ='\t', dtype={"rsid": str, "chromosome": str, "position": int, "genotype": str})
sample_2 = pd.read_csv('sample_2_new.txt', delimiter ='\t', dtype={"rsid": str, "chromosome": str, "position": int, "genotype": str})
```

Now, I wanna safe the Y-Chromosomes only, for a later BLAST comparison. So I need the string entries of one column of my dataframe as a continuous string like this `"AATTGCTT..."`.

```
y_1 = sample_1.loc[sample_5['chromosome'] == "Y"]
y_1_blast = y_1.to_string(columns = ["genotype"], header=False, index=False, index_names=False)
```

As the output contained `'\n'` as well, I tried to remove the delimiter by:

```
y_1_blast.rstrip()
```

but that does not work.
I also get the whole output surrounded by `' ... '` which makes me wonder if that's the problem.

Comment: .rstrip() doesn't change the string in place. It returns a stripped copy. So you'd want to use "y_1_blast = y_1_blast.rstrip()".  See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html

Answer (score 0):

Yep !
If the output is really a continuous string you could choose Regular Expression replacement startegy.

```
import re

# TEST DATA #
y_1_blast = "\nATCG\nATCT\nGAGC\nATGAG\nACGACGTG"

y_1_blast = re.sub('\n', '', y_1_blast)

'ATCGATCTGAGCATGAGACGACGTG'
```

or even more secured (i.e. remove all except any ATGC letters)

```
import re

# TEST DATA #
y_1_blast = "..\nATC.G ATCT\n\nGA..GC ATG_AG\nAC_GA  _CGTG.."

y_1_blast = re.sub("[^ATGC]","",y_1_blast)

'ATCGATCTGAGCATGAGACGACGTG'
```

Comment: `str.replace('\n', '')` will do the job too.